# UIPickerView - make the spin duration longer

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, duration

I have a question regarding the `UIPickerView`. I'm currently writing an application with a `UIPickerView` and a button that spins the `UIPickerView`.

This is the code I currently have for my IBAction spin

```
-(IBAction)spin:(id)sender
{
    [pickerView selectRow: (arc4random() % [myArray count]) inComponent: 0 animated: YES];
}
```

It spins alright but I want the spin duration to be a little bit longer. I want to achieve something like Urbanspoon's slot machine. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: i also face same issue. please can you share your anwer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired behavior, using following code:

```
- (IBAction)spin:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kMySpinDuration];
    NSInteger randomRow = arc4random() % [myArray count];
    [self.picker selectRow: randomRow inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

where kMySpinDuration is your custom animation duration.